# My forms are not coming to my email

Tags: javascript, php, smtp

Why my form is not being sent? is there an error on my php?

Previously my form has no authentication. I had to include the authentication via SMTP because the server need to have to send emails.

Form

```
<form id="contactForm" class="s-form wow zoomInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
    <div class="s-relative">
        <select name="user-topic" id="user-topic" class="m-select">
            <option value="Not select">O que você precisa?</option>
            <option value="Topic 1">Solicitar contato com o vendedor</option>
            <option value="Topic 2">Agendar revisão</option>
            <option value="Topic 3">Cotação de peças</option>
            <option value="Topic 4">Crítica/Sugestão</option>
        </select>
        <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="NOME" value="" name="user-name" id="user-name" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="E-MAIL" value="" name="user-email" id="user-email" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="TELEFONE" value="" name="user-phone" id="user-phone" />
    <textarea id="user-message" name="user-message" placeholder="DEIXE SUA MENSAGEM"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn m-btn">Enviar mensagem<span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></button>
</form>

<script src="assets/contact/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="assets/contact/contact_me.js"></script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require("phpmailer/class.smtp.php");

// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>'true'));
    return false;
}

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->SetLanguage("br");
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->Host = grupomenegalli.com.br; // Endereço do servidor SMTP (caso queira utilizar a autenticação, utilize o host smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usar autenticação SMTP (obrigatório para smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // Protocolo ssl ou tls
$mail->Port = '25'; // Porta do servidor a ser usado
$mail->Username = 'leadsvw@grupomenegalli.com.br'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP (endereço de email)
$mail->Password = '******'; // Senha do servidor SMTP (senha do email usado)


$mail->IsHTML(true);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$mail->Subject = "Contato a partir do site Dimasa VW";

$mensagem = "
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Contato a partir do site Dimasa VW</title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <p>
                Nome: $name<br>

                Email: $email_address<br>

                Telefone: $phone<br>

                Mensagem: $message
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
    ";

$mail->Body = $mensagem;
$xx = $mail->Send();

$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

if($xx){
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true'));
    return true;
}           
?>
```

Script

```
$(function() {
$("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
preventSubmit: true,
submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
    // additional error messages or events
},
submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
    // get values from FORM
    var topic = $("select#user-topic").val();
    var name = $("input#user-name").val();
    var email = $("input#user-email").val();
    var phone = $("input#user-phone").val();
    var message = $("textarea#user-message").val();
    var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
    // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
    if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
        firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            topic: topic,
            name: name,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            message: message
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.error){
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<span>Perdão " + firstName + ", parece que ocorreu uma falha no envio, tente novamente!</span>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            }
            else if(data.success){
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').append("<span>Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso </span>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            }
        }
    })
},
filter: function() {
    return $(this).is(":visible");
},
});
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
$('#success').html('');
});
```

Comment: Please remove your credentials (mail, password) from your code!

Comment: You can check `$mail->ErrorInfo` for the message returned by PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$mail->Host = grupomenegalli.com.br;
```

to this:

```
$mail->Host = "grupomenegalli.com.br";
```

The host should be placed in quotes.

Comment: `$mail->Host = "rupomenegalli.com.br";` I did that, but still does not work

Comment: See my other comment, please do `var_dump($mail->ErrorInfo);` and post the result.